# Windows Defender reported virus after converting c to assembly

Tags: assembly, operating-system

I tried to get assembly code from my sample.c file so i ran

```
gcc -S -m32 sample.c
gcc -o hello_asm -m32 sample.s
```

but after this windows defender reported Trojan in WIN32 directory, does anyone know why is so?

Comment: And the "hello_asm" binary was stored in WIN32 directory? If not, then it is probably unrelated (unless the gcc itself is infected, writing both your "hello_asm" elsewhere, and some trojan into WIN32 directory). ... I think it's lot more likely you didn't describe the problem accurately (what was detected where, and what and where you built).

Comment: it happened like instantly when i created file i doubt it's unrelated

Comment: and the reported file was the produced binary, or which one? Do you understand what compilation is doing? It just writes file to system. If you did compile some kind of trojan/virus source, then yes, you can gain infected binary, but that's just writing it, not executing it, so this is almost harmless (as long as you know what you are doing). But let's say the `sample.c` is not virus/trojan, then the written binary can (and it **can**) be infected only when either the compiler is already infected and the virus has seen writing it new binary, adding itself to it, or your OS is already infected.

Comment: If some completely other file got infected meanwhile, then either the gcc is infected causing your OS to be infected and the infection did start to spread immediately by attacking some other files, or your OS was already infected and it's just coincidence it happened at the same time. Also some antivirus solutions have strong heuristics to detect new viruses, which can often mistake simple executables from programmer with virus/trojan, as the code is unreasonably short and doing non-sense things, and it is not installed by digitally signed installer. So: what actually was infected and where?

Comment: In other words, if you would report some "generic/heuristic/unknown" trojan/virus in your new binary, and your source is just some testing example, then it's by 99% false positive of AV misunderstanding your new piece of own code. But usually people don't compile files in "WIN32" directory (I wouldn't expect that), so from your original post it looks like something else got infected, that may be worth of some more checking with full scan of system/etc... Under normal circumstances with valid gcc, running it will 100% not infect anything elsewhere, even if you would build virus.exe from sources